# compiling AOSP in xperia L

Tags: android, android-source, sony, sony-xperia

I am trying to compile xperia L as mentioned in the github. I downloaded the binary file for xperia L from the below link

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/software-binaries-for-xperia-l

I am not able to compile for xperia L. I am able to compile aosp for xperia z and also tried generic build for emulator.

I found akmd8963 is mentioned in the c2105-vendor.mk file found in binary zip file.The error is

make: *** No rule to make target `vendor/sony/c2105/proprietary/system/bin/akmd8963′, needed by`out/target/product/c2105/system/bin/akmd8963′. Stop.

I didn't find akmd8963 in the zip file. Is there a mistake in the zip file? Did any one tried compiling aosp for xperia L?

Comment: Did you try asking this in the building ASOP mailing list? or does there exist a Sony forum for this type of question?

Comment: Thanks. I posted that in that forum too. http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Android-development/Compiling-AOSP-for-XPERIA-L/m-p/485405

Answer (score 1):

Sony's zip does not include akmd8963 so you will need to pull it from your device (system/bin/akmd8963) or delete that line from the c2105-vendor.mk

I do not work for Sony Mobile. I am just a CyanogenMod developer (i don't speak as the whole project).